# Rotate image (Interview Question) using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

You are given an n x n 2D matrix that represents an image. Rotate the image by 90 degrees (clockwise).

**sample input:**

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

**Sample output:**

```
 [[7, 4, 1],
  [8, 5, 2],
  [9, 6, 3]]
```

I've tried to solve it using numpy

**My code:**

```
def rotateImage(a):
    m = numpy.array(a,int)
    m = numpy.rot90(m,3)
    print (m)
```

**Result:**

```
 Input: a: [[1,2,3], 
            [4,5,6], 
            [7,8,9]]
       
 Output:  null  

 Expected Output: [[7,4,1], 
                   [8,5,2], 
                   [9,6,3]]

 Console Output:  [[7 4 1]
                   [8 5 2]
                   [9 6 3]]
```

To add comma I've also tried using `print (repr(m))`

but it doesn't match with the expected output.

```
array([[7, 4, 1],
       [8, 5, 2],
       [9, 6, 3]])
```

Am I missing anything? Is there any other way to solve this ??

Comment: Try this: `def rotate(a): return np.rot90(a, -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By comparing the expected output and console output I notice that one is a list where as the other is an array

```
 Expected Output: [[7,4,1], 
                   [8,5,2], 
                   [9,6,3]]

 Console Output:  [[7 4 1]
                   [8 5 2]
                   [9 6 3]]
```

Maybe try converting array to list using `.tolist()` method

```
def rotateImage(a):
    m = numpy.array(a,int)
    m = numpy.rot90(m,3)
    return m.tolist()
```